# Proof that the Axiom of Continuity is unique.

Tags: game-theory

First I will outline the notation that I am going to use. A preference relation of player $i$ over a set of outcomes $O$ is a binary relation denoted by $\succeq_i$.

$x \succeq_i y$ is read "player $i$ prefers $x$ to $y$ or is indifferent between the two outcomes".

$x \succ_i y$ is read "player $i$ prefers $x$ to $y$.

$ x \approx_i y$ is read "player $i$ is indifferent between the two outcomes".

A lottery $L$ in which outcome $A_k$ has probability $p_k$ is denoted by $L = [p_1(A_1),...,p_K(A_K)]$

Now a pair of axioms:

***Continuity***

> For every triplet of outcomes $A \succeq_i B  \succeq_i C$ there exists a number $\theta_i \in [0,1]$ such that $$B \approx_i [\theta_i(A), (1-\theta_i)(C)].$$

***Monotonicity***

> Let $\alpha, \beta$ be numbers in $[0,1]$, and suppose that $A \succ_i B$. Then
> $$\alpha \geq \beta \iff [\alpha(A), (1-\alpha)(B)] \succeq_i [\beta(A), (1-\beta)(B)]$$

The theorem I need to prove is

> If the preference relation $\succeq_i$ is transitive and satisfies the above axioms, and if $A \succeq_i B  \succeq_i C$, and $A \succ_i C$, then the value of $\theta_i$ in ***continuity*** is unique.

Since $A \succeq_i B  \succeq_i C$, by ***continuity*** there exists a number $\theta_i \in [0,1]$ such that $B \approx_i [\theta_i(A), (1-\theta_i)(C)]$. Suppose this number is not unique. That is, there exists $\hat{\theta_i} \in [0,1]$ such that $B \approx_i [\hat{\theta_i}(A), (1-\hat{\theta_i})(C)]$ and $\theta_i > \hat{\theta_i}$ without loss of generality.

Since $A \succ_i C$ then by ***monotonicity***
$$\theta_i > \hat{\theta_i}\iff [\theta_i(A), (1-\theta_i)(C)] \succ_i [\hat{\theta_i}(A), (1-\hat{\theta_i})(C)] \iff B \succ_i B$$

Which is a contradiction.

I think I have used ***monotonicity*** incorrectly. Can I have some direction on how to prove this correctly? Or In the event that it is correct can I have some comments on my (in my opinion) incorrect usage of the monotonicity axiom?

Comment: There is something confusing about your notation. "$\approx_i$" and the inequalities are defined being between "outcomes". Then you define a lottery as an assignment of probabilties to outcomes. But then in your axioms, you treat lotteries as if they themselves were outcomes. Can you explain how a lottery is an "outcome"?

Comment: The relation $\succeq_i$ is actually defined over compound lotteries. But we treat outcomes as trivial lotteries $[0(A_1),...,0(A_{k-1}),1(A_k),0(A_{k+1}),...,0(A_K)]$

Comment: You are correct that you have misused monotonicity.  You have assumed that if $[\alpha(A), (1-\alpha)(B)] \approx_i [\beta(A), (1-\beta)(B)]$, then $\alpha = \beta$. The implication in the other direction is obviously true, since the lotteries would be the same, but I see no reason a player cannot find a range of probabilities between two outcomes to be equally acceptable. That is, a player may be indifferent to probabilities for $A$ from $25\%$ to $75\%$, even though probabilities below $25\%$ are less preferable and those above $75\%$ are more preferable.

Comment: There seems to be an assumption that if a player finds $A$ preferable to $C$, then the higher the probability of getting $A$ is, the more preferable a lottery between $A$ and $C$ will be. I believe this to be dependent on exactly what counts as an "outcome". As a final "end of all things" result, it makes sense. But if outcomes can be considered preparatory for later actions, those later actions may cancel out any gain for getting $A$ more often within a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no need to mention multiple players, I will drop the subscript $i$.

You have provided us with no axiom that allows us to conclude $A \succ B$. It is perfectly consistent with the axioms you have stated that it is never the case that $A \succ B$, regardless of the behaviour of $\approx$ and $\succeq$. There are also plenty of other bizarre pathologies that could occur in the absence of relationships between $\succ$ and $\succeq$. Therefore, I do not see how you can conclude that $\theta_i > \hat{\theta}_i \implies [\theta_i(A), (1 - \theta_i)(C)] \succ [\hat{\theta}_i(A), (1 - \hat{\theta}_i)(C)]$. You *can* conclude that $\theta_i > \hat{\theta_i}$ means both that $[\theta_i(A), (1 - \theta_i)(C)] \succeq [\hat{\theta}_i(A), (1 - \hat{\theta}_i)(C)]$ and that it is not the case that $[\hat{\theta}_i(A), (1 - \hat{\theta}_i)(C)] \succeq [\theta_i(A), (1 - \theta_i)(C)]$.

In order to properly solve this problem, we require some additional axioms regarding the behaviour of $\succeq$ and of $\approx$. We now require the following claim, which you have not stated:

> Claim: for all $A$, $B$, if $A \approx B$, then $A \succeq B$ and $B \succeq A$.

Now suppose we have $A \succeq B \succeq C$ and $A \succ C$. Suppose we had $\alpha$, $\beta \in [0, 1]$ such that $B \approx [\alpha(A), (1 - \alpha)(C)]$ and $B \approx [\beta(A), (1 - \beta)(C)]$. Then by our claim, we have $[\beta(A), (1 - \beta)(C)] \succeq B \succeq [\alpha(A), (1 - \alpha)(C)]$. By transitivity, we have $[\beta(A), (1 - \beta)(C)] \succeq [\alpha(A), (1 - \alpha)(C)]$. By monotonicity, we have $\beta \geq \alpha$. Repeat the above argument with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ switched to see that $\alpha \geq \beta$. Therefore, $\alpha = \beta$.